# Pre-training or using the existing model of FastText?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, fasttext

I am planning to create a classification model. Instead of using traditional models, I decided to use a new technique of creating word embeddings, clustering them using k-means, then use the mean of each cluster for comparision with the input(s). I decided to use fasttext as it supports subwords. I also have a large unsupervised text data. I would like to know if I should train the fasttext model with the data I have or I can go with the pre-trained model. If I should train, what are the benefits? Can someone explain me please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should try them both an see which scores better on whatever repeatable quality evaluation you'll be using to make other tuning choices.

There's a fair chance, but no guarantee, that with enough of your own domain text data, your own trained model will better capture the words/subwords of your domain.

But there's no firm rule-of-thumb on how much is "enough", for either most projects or more importantly *your* specific project, or how much the text and word-meanings in your area may be different from the more generic word-meaning in others' pretrained models. So you have to test them against each other - which shouldn't be hard. (Run once with your best-trained model, or several variants of it, then with one or more external pretrained models from others. Compare the results. Choose the best.)

Note that your "new technique" sounds like a pretty common naive but intuitively-attractive classification approach – compute one "average" vector to represent each known class, compute a vector for each candidate text, predict the class with the nearest vector for each text. Or: report the relative distances as ranked possibilities.

It is likely to perform poorly compared to traditional approaches, even very quick & simple approaches, because they will not squeeze as much of the available learning data into a simplistic model where each class is exactly "around" a single summary point. Real categories are often of diverse irregular shapes in the learning data, & the way usual techniques can learn that 'lumpiness', rather than reducing classes to a single centroid point, will do better.

(If you are in fact computing distances to multiple unlabeled clusters, larger than your number of final labels, then using *those* distances as input to a typical learned classifier, it may perform better than the 1-center-per-class approach I describe above. It will have then retained a bit more of the original learnable "shapes" and decision-boundaries in the original data. But again, traditional classifiers, with adequate feature choices/enrichment, are likely to subsume and exceed any value from that style of model.)